# Getting current time that changes dynamically after every statement is executed

Tags: python

The question is very straight forward.
Observe the code below:

```
import time, datetime
timer = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print timer + " This is a test"
time.sleep(5) # 5 seconds until next statement
print timer + " Test after 5 seconds, so the timer should've changed"
```

Results after executing the code:

```
13:22:07 This is a test
13:22:07 Test after 5 seconds, so the timer should've changed
```

As you see in the results, the timer is sleep the same.
I would've accepted it if we're talking about minutes here, but the number of seconds remained unchanged in the code results.

How would we go about using a timer that dynamically changes after executing one statement at a time?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')` to `timer` variable current time assign to `timer` variable.

So after 5 second just reassign `timer` variable with current time[5 second later]
Try This One

```
import time, datetime
timer = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print timer + " This is a test"
time.sleep(5) # 5 seconds until next statement
timer = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print timer + " Test after 5 seconds, so the timer should've changed"
```

Comment: Besides the answers from the others, you might be more happy with time.clock() for exact measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `timer` again. Instead use `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')` again. This will generate a new string with the time. Once you have assigned the string to `timer`, it will not change automatically.

The following should work:

```
import time, datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " This is a test"
time.sleep(5) # 5 seconds until next statement
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') + " Test after 5 seconds, so the timer should've changed"
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code, `timer` is nothing but a string containing the value of the current time when you ran the code. You are simply printing it out twice, with a 5 second sleep in between. But that will not change its value.

You need to rerun the line: `datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')` every time you want to refresh the time.